# How to implement an eventable type in Dart

Tags: events, design-patterns, dart

Is there built in functionality to make eventable types in dart?

In my Javascript applications I use a class called Eventable to provide the following functionality:

```
var dog = new Dog() //where Dog inherits from Eventable
var cat = new Cat() //where Cat inherits from Eventable

//use 'on' to listen to events
cat.on(dog, 'bark', cat.runaway); //assuming Cat has a method runaway on its prototype

//use fire to launch events
dog.fire({type: 'bark'});  //this causes cat.runaway(event); to be called
```

A very common pattern in javascript, I like it because it helps me to keep objects isolated in the src and in my mind.

Using the `on` method creates a `new EventContract` which has a unique key based on the owner (`cat` above), client (`dog` above), type (`'bark'` above) and  function (`cat.runaway` above). This unique key allows me to ensure that no duplicated `EventContract`s are created, but more importantly it allows me to keep an easy to lookup collection of all of the `EventContract`s an object has, such that I can call:

```
cat.dispose();
```

and all of the event contracts for `cat` will be destroyed, so I am confident that all of the external references to cat have been deleted and cat can now be GC'd.

But I am finding it hard to implement this functionality in Dart, because doing something like: `cat.on(dog, 'bark', cat.runaway);` causes a new function to be generated to enclose `(){cat.runaway();}` and the only unique key I can get off of a standard function object in dart is its hashCode, but that means I can recall `cat.on(dog, 'bark', cat.runaway);` and it will create a new `EventContract` because it has created another unique closure rather than processing a reference to the original function, as happens in javascript.

Is there anyway for me to achieve this pattern in dart?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, you should use [`Stream`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/Stream.html) as idiomatic way to provide a sequence of events in Dart. Besides, it is preferred to have events exlpicitly declared on the source (e.g. `onBark` instead of `on['bark']`. Something like this should get you started:

```java
class Dog {
  var _barkController = new StreamController();
  Stream get onBark => _barkController.stream.asBroadcastStream();
  void bark() => _barkController.add("woof");
}

class Cat {
  void runaway() => print("cat running");
}

void main() {
  var dog = new Dog();
  var cat = new Cat();

  // listen returns subscription object which you can use to unsubscribe
  var sub = dog.onBark.listen((event) => cat.runaway()); 

  dog.bark();  // prints 'cat running'
  sub.cancel();
  dog.bark();  // doesn't print anything
}
```

if you prefer to have events declared dynamically, you could have something like this:

```java
  var sub = dog.on['bark'].listen((event) => cat.runaway()); 
  // in this case `on` is a property of some Events type which overrides
  // operator[] to return appropriate Stream
```

There already is a similar [Events class](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Events.html), used to provide browser events on DOM elements.

Additionally, there are community libraries [event_stream](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/event_stream) and [event_source](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/event_source) which simplify this task a bit.

Comment: sure, it is a property accessor: http://www.dartlang.org/articles/idiomatic-dart/#fields-getters-and-setters